# Enabling SSL endpoints in azure container services

Tags: azure, containers

I have been trying to add SSL endpoints to my application hosted on azure container service.
I am following the article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-group-ssl#create-a-self-signed-certificate

This article works well for the application hosted on port 80 . 
The article says to open port 443 only, but my application does not run in this case (my application is hosted on 8000).
When I open 8000, No SSL endpoints are added.

My Deployment.yaml file is

```
api-version: 2018-10-01 location: eastus name: starter properties:   containers:
  - name: nginx-with-ssl
    properties:
      image: nginx
      ports:
      - port: 443
        protocol: TCP
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1.0
          memoryInGB: 1.5
      volumeMounts:
      - name: nginx-config
        mountPath: /etc/nginx
  - name: xxx
    properties:
      environmentVariables:
      image: xxx
      ports:
      - port: 8000
        protocol: TCP
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1.0
          memoryInGB: 4  
   volumes:
  - secret:
      ssl.crt: xxx
      ssl.key: xxx
      nginx.conf: xxx
    name: nginx-config   imageRegistryCredentials:
  - server: xxx
    username: xxx
    password: xxx   ipAddress:
    ports:
    - port: 443
      protocol: TCP
    dnsNameLabel: xxx
    type: Public  
    osType: Linux tags: null
  type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

you are supposed to configure nginx to do the proxying and configuring ssl\redirection etc. [this part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-group-ssl#create-nginx-configuration-file) covers this in some details. but in principle this is something you should do with nginx (inside your nginx configuration file), not with ACI.

You are better off asking nxing configuration question on server fault.